# How to prevent BADUSB attacks in debian 9 stretch?

Tags: linux, debian, security, linux-kernel, usb

is this udev-rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/10-usb-deny.rules :

```
ACTION=="add", ATTR{bInterfaceClass}=="*" \
RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 0 >/sys$DEVPATH/../authorized'"

ACTION=="add", ATTR{bDeviceClass}=="*" \
RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 0 >/sys$DEVPATH/../authorized'"
```

sufficient to prevent BadUsb attacks?

Digging a bit deeper into the rabbit hole:
Anything handled by usb-storage driver passes by that rule.
So thumbdrives to usb-SSDs are still a threat.

Adding:

```
install usb-storage /bin/true
```

to /etc/modprobe.d/usb-storage.conf

is the next obvious thing to do, if I want to be on the safe side.

The rabbit hole is even much deeper: Anything with a filesystem passes by that rule and can be activated by USBdevices. So CD/DVD and SDcards are probably the most common hardware to block.

Adding:

```
install cdrom /bin/true
```

to /etc/modprobe.d/cdrom.conf

and

```
install mmc-core /bin/true
```

to /etc/modprobe.d/mmc-core.conf

will block CD/DVD and SDcards. These three fakeinstalls should be sufficient on standard hardware.

On a Laptop or a system with SSH-access you could alternatively fakeinstall

**usbcore** and **mmc-core**

instaed as there you don't need keyboard or mouse.